# How to use value generated from nested foreach loop, outside the loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

This is **my array**:

```
$categories = array(
    "0" => array( 
        "name" => "All",
        "id" => "100",
        "sub" => array(
                   "0" => "All",
                 "100" => "Limited Sales",
                ),
     ),
    "1" => array( 
        "name" => "Costumes",
        "id" => "200",
        "sub" => array(
                   "0" => "All",
                 "100" => "Male",
                 "200" => "Female",
                 "300" => "Etc",
                ),
     ),
    "2" => array( 
        "name" => "Accessory",
        "id" => "300",
        "sub" => array(
                   "0" => "All",
                 "100" => "Bracelets",
                 "200" => "Rings",
                 "300" => "Necklaces",
                 "400" => "Etc",
                ),
     ),
    "3" => array( 
        "name" => "Convenience",
        "id" => "400",
        "sub" => array(
                   "0" => "All",
                 "100" => "Cards",
                 "200" => "Potions",
                 "300" => "Buffs",
                 "400" => "Etc",
                ),
     ),
);
```

And this is **my current loop** codes:

```
    $cat1 = (int)$_GET['CategoryFirst'];
    $cat2 = (int)$_GET['CategorySecond'];
    
    
    if(!empty($categories)){
        
        echo "<div class='itemCategory'>";
        $m = 0;
        foreach( $categories as $key => $val ){
            $catMain = $val['id'];
                echo "<dl>";
                echo "<dt>".$val['name']."</dt>";
                $s = 0;
                $end = count($val['sub']);
                if($catMain == $cat1) { 
                    $firstCat = $val['name']; 
                } else { 
                    $firstcat = '';
                }   
                foreach($val['sub'] as $subkey => $subval){
                    if($catMain == $cat1 && $subkey == $cat2){ 
                        $on = 'on';
                    } else { 
                        $on = ''; 
                    }
                    if($catMain == $cat1 && $subkey == $cat2) {
                        $secondCat = $subval; 
                    } else {
                        $secondCat = ''; 
                    }
                    if ($s == $end - 1) {
                        $last = ' last'; 
                    }else{ 
                        $last = ''; 
                    }

                   // If i echo $secondCat here it returns the correct data of $subval

                    echo "<dd".$last." class='".$on.$last."'><a href='?CategoryFirst=".$catMain."&CategorySecond=".$subkey."&Sort=0&SearchString='>".$subval."</a></dd>";
                     $s++;               
                     
                }           
                echo "</dl>";
                $m++;
        }   
        echo "</div>";  
    
    } 

//NEED HELP HERE - $secondCat returns nothing
    echo "<h3>".$firstCat.$secondCat."</h3>";
```

As you can see on the codes,i used **$catmain**, **$subkey** and the **$_GET['CategoryFirst']**, **$_GET['CategorySecond']** for comparing so if the users current page have matching values of those four, the link is **highlighted**

I was able to achieve that, but this time i needed something more. I need to be able to print the **$subval** from the 2nd foreach and use it outside of the loop to put it inside the

tag.

I was successfully able to do it on **$firstCat** but the **$secondCat** returns **nothing**.

But if tried echoing $secondCat inside the nested foreach loop, it returns the correct $subval data.

What should i do to make the $secondCat to print the correct data similar to $firstCat on the H3 tag (outside loop)?

Comment: What about removing `else {$secondCat = ''; }` statement? Imagine your data is somewhere in between (middle) of array, once it gets to the next row, it will set `$secondCat = ""`.

Comment: @NcXNaV Holy cow!! That solved it :D Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your inner foreach:

```php
                foreach($val['sub'] as $subkey => $subval){
                    if($catMain == $cat1 && $subkey == $cat2){ 
                        $on = 'on';
                    } else { 
                        $on = ''; 
                    }
                    if($catMain == $cat1 && $subkey == $cat2) {
                        $secondCat = $subval; 
                    }
                    if ($s == $end - 1) {
                        $last = ' last'; 
                    }else{ 
                        $last = ''; 
                    }

                   // If i echo $secondCat here it returns the correct data of $subval

                    echo "<dd".$last." class='".$on.$last."'><a href='?CategoryFirst=".$catMain."&CategorySecond=".$subkey."&Sort=0&SearchString='>".$subval."</a></dd>";
                     $s++;               
                     
                }
```

This should work, cause the variable will not be overridden with an empty string and will be preserved outside of the loops.

Comment: @Amenadiel If this answer is working, could you please accept / upvote for future visitors?

Comment: Done! :D Sorry i forgot to.